# carousel slide not working for static images in django

Tags: django, carousel, django-bootstrap3

I am new to Django, I am trying to use bootstrap carousel in Django, all images are getting loaded, but slider is not working.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Monitoring/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
<script src="{% static 'Monitoring/js/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js' %}" ></script>
<script src="{% static 'Monitoring/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js' %}"> </script>
<style>
    .carousel-inner{
    height:600px !important;

    }
</style>
```

Below is the body :

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width:100%;">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="{% static 'Monitoring/media/login/image1.png' %}" alt="Chania" height="600" width="100%">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="{% static 'Monitoring/media/login/image2.png' %}" alt="Chania" height="600" width="100%">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="{% static 'Monitoring/media/login/image3.png' %}" alt="Chania" height="600" width="100%">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Also, is there any better way to read all images from a particular folder and use them for carousel slider. In the above code, I am doing same thing for all three images, is it possible to do the same with loop all images in folder.

Comment: Have you checked in your console that the JS is being correctly loaded?

Comment: @solarissmoke : Yes, i can see bootstrap.min.js is loaded but carousel.js is not loaded.

Answer (score 3):

```
the below mentioned script works with inclusion of bootstrap 4 in your <head> tag


**<!-- Slideshow container -->
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100 h-50" src="{% static 'images/IMG_1972.JPG' %}" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100 h-50" src="{% static 'images/IMG_1972.JPG' %}" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100 h-50" src="{% static 'images/IMG_1972.JPG' %}" alt="First slide">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>**
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get more control over images, you have to save images in the model. Then you can iterate through your images through the loop as many times as you want.

```
 <div class="carousel-inner">

  {% for i in your_view_context %}
    <div class="item">
      <img src="{{i.image.url}}" alt="Chania" height="600" width="100%">
    </div>
{% endfor %}

  </div>
```

Your model will be:

```
class ImageModel(models.MODEL):
    image = models.ImageField(blank = False, null = False)
```

Your view will be:

```
def myview(request):
    queryset = ImageModel.objects.all()
    context = {
                your_view_context = queryset
              }
    return render(request, 'template.html' , context)
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i dont want to store images in db. i want to have it as static files. why my code (basically slider) is not working with django however without django its working smooth.